# Ways of merging remote master branch to local branch (other than master)

Tags: git

I work on multiple branches. when I need to sync my branch with main branch (let's say `master`), I do

```
git pull origin master
```

So I get latest changes from my coworkers commited to main branch.

But I started to think, if it's enough to update main branch (so I don't get behind it as well) with

```
git checkout master
git pull #this will update master branch to have latest changes
```

and then merge only locally:

```
git checkout otherBranch
git merge master # will it merge latest changes of remote master barnch ?
```

So, concisely, will those two be equivalent:

```
git pull origin master #when on other branch
```

and

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout otherBranch
git merge master
```

Second will update two branches, but connection to remote is made only once, that's why I would prefer the second approach if it's valid.

Comment: Btw without switching branches you can do `git fetch origin master:master` which will update `master` without you having to do a checkout first. Then you can just `git merge master` or `git rebase master` whichever you prefer.

Comment: @CoryKramer Well great tip with shortcut to update branch without checking out. So `git fetch origin otherBranch:master` would try to merge `master` in my local `otherBranch` ?

Comment: @CoryKramer So, from your comment I guess it will work as I expect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `git pull` essentially just does a `fetch` and a `merge` (unless you configure it to behave otherwise - for example, to rebase).

So to answer your question, yes, it will work. If you want to execute less commands you should also use what [@Cory-Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/cory-kramer) suggested.

Note that doing `git fetch origin otherBranch:master` will not attempt to *merge* `master` into `otherBranch` but will instead try to *update* `master` from `otherBranch`:

1. The syntax is `<src>:<dest>`
2. It doesn't merge, it updates the ref

In your case the update would have been rejected unless you forced it which you shouldn't because it won't do what you wanted.

Using the command `git fetch origin otherBranch:master` as Cory suggested only saves you from checking out master to fetch and then checking out your branch again. You still have to do the merge.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```